# Pasar valor de un input como parámetro a Route

Tags: php, laravel-livewire

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Laravel + Livewire y necesito pasar el valor de un input como parámetro a una ruta definida mediante Route. He creado el siguiente componente livewire:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-12 text-Busquedas">
        <input type="text" placeholder="¿Qué estas buscando...?">
        <a href="{{ route('SeleccionarItems') }}" class="btBuscar btn btn-success"><img class="ima" src="{{ asset('imgs/icoBuscar.png') }}"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

y lo que no estoy pudiendo hacer es enviar el contenido del input como parámetro  de la ruta SeleccionarItems. Lo que intento hacer es poner un campo de búsqueda, y luego  mostrar en una siguiente página, los valores que me coinciden con la cadena de búsquedas.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.